# trying to convert functions to c++ how do I change target to scene component

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

[image]

grapplecomponent.h

```
 protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        bool m_hooked;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        bool m_hookfinished;
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        FVector m_hook_location;
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
        void m_set_visibility(const bool new_visibility, const bool propagate_to_children);
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
        void m_setworldlocation(const FVector& new_location, const bool sweep, const bool teleport, FHitResult& sweep_hit_result);
```

grapplecomponent.cpp

```
void Agrapplecomponent:: m_set_visibility(const bool new_visibility, const bool propagate_to_children)
{
    
}

void Agrapplecomponent::m_setworldlocation(const FVector& new_location, const bool sweep, const bool teleport, FHitResult& sweep_hit_result)
{
    
}
```

I have no idea how to change the target of m_setworldlocation and m_set_visibility to scene component like the normal blueprint function does how do I fix this? the stuff that starts with an M are converted to c++

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make much sense. Why are you recreating existing built-in functions?

Comment: @Rotem because converting blueprint functions to c++ makes the project run better

Comment: You don't seem to understand what "Target is ..." means.
It's the **Class the function originates from**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SetVisibility and SetWorldLocation functions already have a C ++ implementation.

Better to call the entire function from C ++:

```
//.h
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void StopGrapple();
//.cpp
void Agrapplecomponent::StopGrapple()
{
    FVector Location(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    m_hooked = false;
    m_hookfinished = false;
    GrappleHookCable->SetVisibility(false);
    GrappleHookCable->SetWorldLocation(Location);
}
```

*Update*

In the Blueprint, change the name of the GrappleHookCable to BlueprintGrappleHookCable. Save and Compile. Close UE.

In {ProjectName}.build.cs add "CustomMeshComponent"

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "UMG", "CustomMeshComponent"});
```

Character:

```
//.h

#include "CustomMeshComponent.h"


UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly)
UCustomMeshComponent*   GrappleHookCable;

//.cpp

Construct
{
    GrappleHookCable = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCustomMeshComponent>(TEXT("GrappleHookCable"));
    GrappleHookCable->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());
}
```

Compile. Open project. Open Blueprint. Variables -> Components ->  Right click "BlueprintGrappleHookCable" -> Replace Reference.

Find "GrappleHookCable" in "Replace with".
Turn on "Only show and replace result from ...".
Click "Find and Replace References in ..."

Comment: thanks for this however when I did this it flagged an error that GrappleHookCable is undefined. I tried fixing this by putting 'UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
  USceneComponent *GrappleHookCable;' in the header but while that stops the code flagging errors upon using this new function it crashes the engine entirely so I'm assuming that's not what I'm supposed to do. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: In Blueprint GrappleHookCable is a SkeletalMeshComponent?

Comment: the one shown in the screenshot is a cable component. when I hover over it in the editor it says "component that allows you to specify custom triangle mesh geometry" does that help?

Comment: sorry for being a pain in the ass but when I type  #include "CustomMeshComponent.h" it says it can't find it. In {ProjectName}.build.cs it says it's not in project so I'm assuming it has something to do with that

Comment: in Visual Studio, in your project directory, go to Source / "Your Project Name" /. There is a file with the extension .Build.cs. Through this file, you can connect different modules to the project.

Comment: wouldn't that be 'PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "UMG", "CustomMeshComponent"});' cause I did that and it says "CustomMeshComponent is missing in project file" and that is in projectname.build.cs

Comment: Comment out the inclusion of "CustomMeshComponent.h", the declaration, and all calls to "GrappleHookCable". Then recompile the whole project (UE must be closed).

Comment: ok so that part is fixed. the last problem is "cannot resolve symbol 'construct'". any idea why this is happening?

Comment: roughly speaking, a constructor is a function that is called before BeginPlay. In it you can initialize variables.

Comment: The creation of the constructor looks like this:        //.h
    
    class PROJECT_API ACustomPlayerController : public APlayerController
    {
     GENERATED_BODY()
     ACustomPlayerController();
    
     ...
    };
    
    //.cpp
    
    ACustomPlayerController::ACustomPlayerController()
    {
     
    }

Comment: the function, which I call "constructor", needs to be placed in the constructor of your class.

Comment: Here are links with more information.: [unrealcommunity.](https://unrealcommunity.wiki/class-sxa2szq9), [forums.unrealengine](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/when-does-the-c-constructor-run/133915)